# How to programmatically change keyboard input type in android (xamarin)

Tags: android, keyboard, xamarin.android, android-inputtype

I need change keyboard input type programmatically. Problem is, that I have only one EditText view component. The activity has many states (stTitle, stQuantity, ...) and keyboard input type have to change when the state has changed.

I tried this:

```
BatchStates State
{
    get {....}
    set
    {
       ...
       etInput.SetRawInputType(Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber);
       ...
    }
}
```

But this change will happen after I will click Enter.
So this change is visible in the next state.

Is possible to refresh keyboard or somethink else?